# UIImage does not save to disk

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uipickerview, archive

Everything works fine, but i have added some code to save the image to disk, once taken and it doesnt seem to work, Does not give me an error either, any ideas?

```
func importPicture(action: UIAlertAction! = nil) {

    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .Camera
    picker.delegate = self
    presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let _ = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    var newImage: UIImage

    if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage"] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else if let possibleImage = info["UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] as? UIImage {
        newImage = possibleImage
    } else {
        return
    }

    let imageName = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let imagePath =          getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)

    if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 80) {
        jpegData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)

    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    images.insert(newImage, atIndex: 0)
    collectionView.reloadData()

    if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage)
        var error: NSError?
        do {
            try mcSession.sendData(imageData!, toPeers: mcSession.connectedPeers, withMode: .Reliable)
        }
        catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
        }

        if error != nil {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send error", message:     error!.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            presentViewController(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}

func getDocumentsDirectory() -> NSString {


    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,   .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    return documentsDirectory
}
```

Comment: Did you check Documents directory for saved files? How do you know it does not work?

Comment: Use the version of writeToFile with error reporting: `func writeToFile(_ path: String, options writeOptionsMask: NSDataWritingOptions) throws` and handle/report any errors. If `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` fails there is no error handling reporting. You need to implements all the error handling so you can know when and where there are problems.

Comment: Try using another way of generating the file name. a sequence generator or just timeStamp + .jpg

Comment: Thanks guys i used this line instead    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil)
```

Used this instead, tested and works fine